# Failed to compile in React.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, tailwind-css

I ran into this problem when am following this video tutorial until here: https://youtu.be/nGoSP3MBV2E?list=PLIZkq64ad9C4POK0E1fhCaxlxTXwr7wSh&t=5413. After i restart my computer the next day, the crash happen. I don't know what cause it since I have followed some tutorial on how to fix my problem and see no result:
[Problem when](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOB4C.jpg)

Here's the source code of the failed code:

Header.js
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMjs.png)

layout.js:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIoj.png)
Source code Github:

I have tried fixing any typo in the program, went as far as re-doing the whole tutorial from begin but whenever I exit my project, the problem emerge again.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you have moved your Header component to a different folder? Make sure that it exists in the directory in the import statement.

Try this if you are on Windows.

1. Delete the import statement. It should display 'Cannot find Header' error.
2. Place your cursor at the end of the component tag
3. ctrl + .
4. Select the correct import path (usually at the top)

Comment: thank you, after deleting the import statement like you suggest, the app asked provide me with a quickfix like the following: 
import Hero from "../components/layout/Hero";
Simply replacing "@" with ".." fix this problem for me

Comment: @GiaKhánhLê I'm glad I could help! Please accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution.

Comment: @GiaKhánhLê Next time, just make sure to import components like you just did instead of writing the import statement yourself to avoid errors like this. The person in the tutorial might be using something like babel-plugin-root-import or has something setup in their tsconfig/jsconfig file. The @ is a custom or alias path.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing "@" with ".." fix this problem for me